# Regex: 1 number or 2 numbers

Tags: regex, expression

I need to check for a link where title="Week 1" or title="Week 13", I have tried somethings what I found on the internet but it won`t work:

http://regexr.com?38bet

So, how to match if something have one number or two numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match one or two digit number, you may use one of the following patterns:

1. `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d)` - This expression finds 1 or 2 digits that are not enclosed with any other digit, so it will find a match in `a12b`, `1`, `12`, `a_1_b`, `x_23` strings. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nggn65/1).
2. `\b\d{1,2}\b` - This regex is similar to the above one with one exception: it won't match if there are letters or underscores on either end. So, it will match in `-1-`, `,23,` but won't match in `a_23_b` or `a12b`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nggn65/2).
3. `(?<!\S)\d{1,2}(?!\S)` - This expression will match one or two digits ONLY between whitespace characters or start/end of string (within whitespace boundaries). So, it will match in `a 12 b`, `a 12`, `12 b`, but won't match in `12a`, `-12-`, `12_`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nggn65/3).
4. `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)\d{1,2}(?!\.?\d)` - This regex will match one or two digits that is not a part of a number, as there cannot be a digit or a digit followed with a dot (you may need to adjust the pattern for other decimal separators) before the two digits, and there cannot be a dot and digit or just a digit after the two digits. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nggn65/4).
5. Yes, if your string is just these two digts, use anchors, `^\d{1,2}$`, or `\A\d{1,2}\z` (`\A\d{1,2}\Z` in Python `re`). Note `\z` (`\Z` in Python `re`) is preferred if you want to handle multiline inputs). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nggn65/5).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\d{1,2}`  This will match between 1 and 2 digits.

I have also found that the following [this](http://regexpal.com/) website is very helpful when I need to write regexes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a zero-or-one quantifier (`?`), like this:

```
title="[Ww]eek [1-9][0-9]?"
```

This will match a string which contains `title="` followed by an upper- or lower-case `w`, followed by `eek`, a space, and digit from `1` to `9`, followed by an optional digit from `0` to `9`, followed by a `"`.

You should also consider using the case-insensitive flag in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which context you're using the regular expression.

- In python, `?` will match 0 or 1 characters.
- In JavaScript, `?` will also match 0 or 1 characters.
- In vi, `\=` will match 0 or 1 characters.

So the answer(s) would be:

```
Python regex:     Week 13?
JavaScript regex: /Week 13?/
vi regex:         Week 13\=
```

Which will match both:

```
Week 1
Week 13
```

Answer (score 0):

for java try this one:

```
String regex = "[\\d{2}]+";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
title="[Ww]eek (\d+)\.pdf"
```

**RegExr :**

http://regexr.com?38bfc

**Matches :**

```
1 
13
```